# Visual C++ & Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-c++

I am trying to use Visual C++ compiler (the one that comes with MS Visual Studio 10) in Eclipse. However, when I use it from Eclipse the compiler does not recognize standard headers.

E.g. an attempt to include iostream results in "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory".

Do I have to set any additional preferences to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "include" path for your environment/project

Answer (score 2):

Search for `vsvars32.bat` file in your hdd. If you can run it before compiling process, your path problems will be solved.

I didn't try this with Eclipse but I'm sure you can find a corresponding feature like the IDEs I have tried.